# Why does string match fails in this "expect" code?

Tags: tcl, expect

I have created the following procedure in expect to work with an Agilent Base Station Simulator:

```
proc get_bss_parameter_value {bss parameter_string} {
global bss_array

set bss_str "$parameter_string?"

puts "String 1"
set bss_str "oa;$bss_array(gpib):$bss_str\r"
send "$bss_str"
expect {nopattern^}

puts "String 2"
set bss_str "en;$bss_array(gpib)"
puts "Sending bss_str: $bss_str"
send "$bss_str\r"
expect .*

set receive_buffer $expect_out(buffer)
puts "receive_buffer START: $receive_buffer"
puts "END"

return $receive_buffer
}
```

========================================================
OUTPUT:

String 1

>

> oa;05:SYST:APPL?
>   String 2
>   Sending bss_str: en;05
>   "CDMA 2000 Lab App T"
>
> can't read "expect_out(buffer)": no such variable
>       while executing
>   "set receive_buffer $expect_out(buffer)"
>       (procedure "get_bss_parameter_value" line 20)

========================================================
If ".*" is replaced by "*" in the above code, this is the OUTPUT:

String 1

>

> oa;05:SYST:APPL?
>   String 2
>   Sending bss_str: en;05
>   receive_buffer START:
>
> oa;05:SYST:APPL?
>
> END
>   Current application is
>
> oa;05:SYST:APPL?

Problem:
1) I am not able to get the value "CDMA 2000 Lab App T" in the expect_out(buffer) variable which should match (due to .*) the output from the Agilent device. Is there something wrong with the code?
2) In both the cases, the command "en;05" is send but not displayed on stdout. Though we can see the expected output in the first case.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the [expect] command by default does [glob-style](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/string.htm#M40) matching, not [regexp-style](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm).  So, where you write:

```
expect .*
```

you are actually looking for a string beginning with a literal dot followed by any number of characters.  As this fails to match, the expect_out array does not get populated.  As you mention

```
expect *
```

behaves as you expect because the glob pattern "*" matches any string.

If you truly want ".*", then you need to specify

```
expect -re .*
set receive_buffer $expect_out(buffer)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was under the impression that the expect_out variable was a global. If I'm correct, then you'd need the following:

```
global expect_out
```

Or, you can refer to it as a global explicitly by using the namespace qualifier "::"

```
set receive_buffer $::expect_out(buffer)
```